# Only finitely many primes dividing the values of an integer polynomial

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

For a given $P\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ call a positive prime $p$ good if there exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p$ divides $P(n)$. Does there exist a non-constant $P$ such that the set of good primes is finite?

Comment: Any constant polynomial only has only finitely many good primes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Given any finite set of primes $S$, the number of positive integers up to $x$ divisible only by primes in $S$ grows like a constant times $(\log x)^{\#S}$. Since the number of values, up to $x$, of a degree-$d$ polynomial grows like a constant times $x^{1/d}$, those values must inevitably include integers with prime factors outside of $S$.

Comment: are you considering values between $-x$ and $x$ (so not exactly up to $x$)?

Comment: @vrz all negative values are composite, or units.

Comment: Yes, one can either restrict to positive values and polynomials with positive leading coefficient, or else consider all integers (between $-x$ and $x$ when appropriate) and ignore the sign when determining prime factors, as is natural. (There's no need to call a negative integer "composite" or "prime" in this setting, but if we must, it makes the most sense to say that $-n$ is prime if and only if $n$ is prime, since $-1$ is a unit.)